# grails bootstrap error writing to mysql

Tags: grails, amazon-web-services

I'm using spring security within a simple app.  The app runs fine locally when connecting to amazon RDS instance.  When I upload my app to elastic beanstalk the creation of a role fails in Bootstrap:

```
def init = { servletContext ->

    println log.name

    log.debug("hello 1")
    def adminRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN')
    log.debug("hello 2")
    if (!adminRole.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)) {
        log.debug("hello 3")
        adminRole.errors.each {
            println it
            log.error(it)
        }
    }

2013-12-17 23:25:33,311 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.nrfa.Role.save() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: save(), save(boolean), save(java.util.Map), wait(), last(), any()
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.nrfa.Role.save() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: save(), save(boolean), save(java.util.Map), wait(), last(), any()
    at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:308)
    at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:301)
    at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.nrfa.Role.save() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: save(), save(boolean), save(java.util.Map), wait(), last(), any()
    at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:15)
    ... 9 more
```

If it were a database connectivity issue - which it may be - I would have thought the error would have been 'hey, can't connect to the database'.  Not the non-descriptive error of can't find Role.save().

EDIT:
Full bootstrap:

```
import com.nrfa.Role
import com.nrfa.User
import com.nrfa.UserRole

class BootStrap {
    def springSecurityService

    def init = { servletContext ->

        println log.name

        log.debug("hello 1")
        def adminRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN')
        log.debug("hello 2")
        if (!adminRole.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)) {
            log.debug("hello 3")
            adminRole.errors.each {
                println it
                log.error(it)
            }
        }
        log.debug("hello 4")
        def userRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

        def testUser = new User(username: 'me', password: 'password')
        testUser.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

        UserRole.create testUser, userRole, true

        assert User.count() == 1
        assert Role.count() == 2
        assert UserRole.count() == 1


    }

    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

EDIT: Include BuildConfig.Groovy:

```
dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.

    //runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.27'

    runtime 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'
}

plugins {
    build ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
    runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
    runtime ":resources:1.2"
    runtime ":mysql-connectorj:5.1.22.1"
    compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC2'


    // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
    //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
    //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
    //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"

    build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

    build ":database-migration:1.3.2"

    compile ':cache:1.0.1'
```

//        runtime ":mysql-connectorj:5.1.22.1"
    }

Comment: I am starting to believe this is an issue creating the war file, and the mysql connector is not getting picked up.  Originally it was a dependency (didn't work).  I changed it to a plugin (still doesn't work).  The tomcat7 install in elastic beanstalk doesn't come with a mysql jar file.

Comment: Can you share your full BootStrap.groovy file?

Comment: full bootstrap added.

Comment: Try `runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"` in plugins section of `BuildConfig`.

Comment: Yes, the runtime of hibernate fixed it.  That caused the appropriate hibernate jar files to be included in the war file.

Answer (score 0):

That error is usually indicative of the hibernate plugin not being installed or working. Can you see the expanded war on the remote server? I'm not familiar with the workings of beanstalk itself so maybe something is in conflict there.

Comment: I've listed my BuildConfig.groovy.  The war file does have some of the hibernate jars - hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final - but not hibernate-core which is listed in my IDE.

Comment: what version of grails are you running? I didn't see it listed. In grails 2.x the "hibernate:$grailsVersion is not longer accepted. it has to be specific. with 2.3.0 for example it is hibernate:3.6.10.M6. in 2.3.4 it is hibernate:3.6.10.2. same with the tomcat plugin. 2.2.34 is 7.0.42

Answer (score 0):

Adding "runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.27'" in dependencies and remove it from plugins?

Comment: That was what I had originally.  The problem was the tomcat7 installation on amazon aws doesn't include the mysql connector jar file, so it never ran properly with this option.

Comment: it definitely goes in the dependencies and not the plugins. that jar isn't a grails plugin after all.